# Calling two ajax in single change event

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

This is my simple ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#purchase_id").change(function () {  
    var purchase_id = $(this).val();
    var followurl  ='<?php echo base_url()."index.php/placeorder_ajax/get_product";?>';
    var followurlTwo  ='<?php echo base_url()."index.php/placeorder_ajax/get_date";?>';
    $.post( followurl, {'purchase_id' : purchase_id}, function(data){

        $.post( followurlTwo, {'purchase_id' : purchase_id}, function(dataTwo){
                alert(dataTwo);
                $("#cart_details").html(data);
                   $("#purchase_order_date").html(dataTwo);

              });


        });     
} );
```

I want to get date from purchase order table on change event of purchase_id and want product list also. so how can call here two ajax??

Comment: Just do another `$.post` in your current one.

Comment: In current success or outside of it??

Comment: Depends, keep in mind that the calls are async.

Comment: where do I put that async attribute

Comment: You don't need to. It's default on. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$.post( followurl, {'purchase_id' : purchase_id}, function(data){

  $("#div1").html(data);

  $.post( followurlTwo, {'purchase_id' : purchase_id}, function(dataTwo){

    $("#div2").html(dataTwo);

  });

});
```

You might consider using a GET for this. Since you're **get**ting data from the url(s).

Also, a best practice would be to use only one PHP page, so you only have to do 1 request per change.

Comment: If you don't need to use data from the first post in the second one, you could also separate them.

Comment: I exactly did this but no luck.. I am getting correct data in that alert also.

Comment: You might need to change how you append the data to your page. Are you getting HTML or JSON?

Comment: I am getting html and id for that div is also correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68271/discussion-between-cas-bloem-and-kedar-b).

Answer (score 0):

In server side script (PHP), you can create an array with two elements, one for purchase order and another for product listing. Then go for a json stringify.

In JS, you can decode the json string and both the data you can get by a single server hit.

Comment: I am getting product details and date from different tables

Comment: You can fetch data from two different table in a single function!!

Comment: Thats true, but not the question he asked.